# Extreme slowness on visual studio startup - creates a great deal of node processes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper-2016

I use Visual Studio 2015 update 2 and Resharper 2016.1.1 on daily basis and since the last update (both where updated on the same day) upon any project startup it creates like 30-50 node processes which suck up my memory and CPU.
For around 15 minutes my pc is unusable due to this. 
When the processes stop executing the pc, VS and R# run smoothly.

Anyone know what might be causing this? What could be creating this node processes?

Comment: Hard to guess what a "node process" might be.  Are you talking about Node.js?  Does it still happen when you disable Resharper?  If it doesn't, did you try JetBrains' support?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes Node.js processes. I've disabled Resharper but the problem persists. Probably a Visual Studio issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could find, Visual Studio creates a node process per package.json in the solution.
At some point in time I had a package.json in multiple projects inside the solution being this likely the cause.